# How to build bootgen utility in Yocto - Makefile system?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to write a recipe to build the bootgen utility natively for my linux pc. Basically, after compiling natively i.e for my X86 machine, I want to use this utility to generate a zynq image.
The bootgen has a dependency on the openssl package - libssl1.0-dev, which I have installed using

sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev

Now, here is my recipe and I am getting errors and I can see it is trying to cross-compile but I want this to build natively rather than cross compiled for ARM/Zynq. Here is my recipe.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Bootgen application - Xilinx to create boot.bin"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/Xilinx/bootgen"
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=be5410bcde8eb6481a6e5d3b22e0740b"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/Xilinx/bootgen.git"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

What I need to provide here? How does it know how to compile? Do I need to add any task like compile here?

Errors seen -

```
    ERROR: bootgen-git-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
    ERROR: bootgen-git-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0/temp/log.do_compile.10667)
    ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0/temp/log.do_compile.10667
    Log data follows:
    | DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
    | NOTE: make -j 4
    | g++ -c  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden   -I. bootheader-zynq.cpp
    | g++ -c  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden   -I. authentication-zynq.cpp
    | g++ -c  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/

 g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmacro-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0’
| g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmacro-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0’
| g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmacro-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0’
| g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmacro-prefix-map=/home/xxx/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bootgen/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/bootgen/git-r0’

| Makefile:70: recipe for target 'bootheader-zynq.o' failed
| make: *** [bootheader-zynq.o] Error 1
| make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| Makefile:70: recipe for target 'imageheadertable-versal.o' failed
| make: *** [imageheadertable-versal.o] Error 1
| Makefile:70: recipe for target 'authentication-zynq.o' failed
| make: *** [authentication-zynq.o] Error 1
| Makefile:70: recipe for target 'bif.yy.o' failed
```

Comment: I could be I didn't understand your question, but the bootgen utility is distributed with Vivado and Vitis [Xilinx] and is a native thing.  Although very nice you would like to build it from code, it's not really needed.

Comment: Yes, but I want to integrate this utility in my build system running on linux.

Comment: But, you have it i your flow if you're using Petalinux/Vitis of Xilinx, no?  Also on Linux.

Comment: I am not using peta linux but using simple plain vanilla yocto to build bootgen.